# Retrieve from multiple tables while only allowing distinct results for one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select from three tables, Regions, Players, and regionplayer.  and order the results by region name, and then by when the players attached to that region where last seen.  I would really like it so that i only return one result for each region, with the player who hasn't been seen the longest.

SQL.

```
SELECT RegionName.*, RegionPlayer.*, Players.*
FROM RegionName
    JOIN RegionPlayer
        ON RegionPlayer.Regionkey = RegionName.Key
    JOIN Players
        ON Players.Key = RegionPlayer.Playerkey
GROUP BY RegionName.Name, Players.Seen DESC
```

some table data.

```
RegionName
    key Name
    1   regionone
    2   regiontwo
    3   regionthree
    4   regionfouor
    5   regionfive

Players
    Key     Name    Seen
    1       jack    2014-03-21 12:43:46
    2       joe     2014-03-26 12:43:46
    3       bob     2014-03-20 12:43:46
    4       bill    2014-03-19 12:43:46
    5       dave    2014-03-17 12:43:46
    6       tina    2014-03-28 12:43:46
    7       tony    2014-03-29 12:43:46
    8       george  2014-03-15 12:43:46
    9       sam     2014-03-18 12:43:46
    10      frank   2014-03-18 12:43:46

RegionPlayer
    key Regionkey   PlayerKey
    1   1           1
    2   1           4
    3   1           5
    4   2           1
    5   2           4
    6   3           6
    7   3           7
    8   4           1
    9   4           8
    10  4           7
    11  5           3
```

Comment: What actually your problem with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take your statement, at first the part before GROUP BY

```
SELECT RegionName.*, RegionPlayer.*, Players.*
FROM RegionName
    JOIN RegionPlayer
        ON RegionPlayer.Regionkey = RegionName.Key
    JOIN Players
        ON Players.Key = RegionPlayer.Playerkey
```

and add

```
WHERE Players.Seen = (
    SELECT MIN(Players2.Seen) 
    FROM RegionName as RegionName2
    JOIN RegionPlayer as RegionPlayer2
        ON RegionPlayer2.Regionkey = RegionName2.Key
    JOIN Players as Players2
        ON Players2.Key = RegionPlayer2.Playerkey
    WHERE RegionName2.Key = RegionName.Key
    )
```

and then GROUP BY from your statement

```
GROUP BY RegionName.Name, Players.Seen DESC
```

The subselect returns the minimum date SEEN from PLAYERS for current region.

Comment: I think I might be missing something, but i get errors becuase RegionPlayer2 doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right. I fixed the statement in the answer. 'RegionPlayer2' should be 'RegionPlayer as RegionPlayer2'. Same for the other two tables in subselect.